# Exception while running simple Word Count spark program from eclipse

Tags: apache-spark

I have been trying to make my simple word count program work in Eclipse. I keep getting the error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data".

Below is the code snippet in my java program.

```
String inputFileName = "pom.xml";
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("wordCount"); 
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext( conf);
JavaRDD<String> linesRdd = sc.textFile(inputFileName);
long countOfLines = linesRdd.count();
```

I am able to submit the jar generated from the above maven project into a spark cluster. But I haven't been able to run the spark program within Eclipse yet. Any help on this is appreciated.

Few other notes

- I am running this on Windows.
- I have already hadoop-commons from https://codeload.github.com/srccodes/hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin/zip/master and copied winutils.exe to fix an issue in spark shell
- Earlier I was getting the error "error: not found: value sqlContext", which is resolved after the above step. I am able to run spark scala commands in shell now.

I get the below exception when linesRdd.count() is called.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2449)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1385)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
....

16/07/22 17:28:10 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2449)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1385)
```

Below is the dependencies and build plugins that are included in my pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>  <!-- 1.6.2 is the latest version, using which Tuple2 class can't be referenced -->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>          
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>  
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Thanks,
Prasanna

Comment: Which Spark binaries did you download? 1.6.2?

Comment: I have downloaded spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6. But from eclipse, I dont think that is being referenced. I am not starting the spark daemon from this binary. Instead I believe the libraries are being referenced from my spark main class. Currently I am point to 1.3.0 version in my pom.xml, since i had an issue with 1.6.2 issue. Is my understanding correct, that I don't need to start excternal 1.6.2 spark daemon?

Comment: No, you *do* need those daemons active. Thecreason it doesn't work is that there's a version mismatch. You meed both code and daemon to be with the same version

Comment: Although I still couldnt make it work on Windows, I am able to run the same piece of java code on Linux (Cent OS). I didnt download and install spark separately. I just had this spark java project. I have an work-around now, although not the best one.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I dont think daemons are required to be running based on the fact that I am able to run it on Linux. Infact as long as the program is running, I was able to access http://localhost:4040/, since the driver spark program within my java project starts a web console listening at 4040 port.

Comment: Are you setting $SPARK_HOME anywhere?

Comment: @Kaushal , I didn't set it earlier. Now I tried setting SPARK_HOME as well. I still get the same issue. Also I don't understand how that would solve. It did not appear that I need to have SPARK installation on my laptop to start  spark programming in the eclipse, based on my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, If you are running Spark in **Local** model then you don't need to install.